# Converting Euclidean Distance into meters using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, distance, units

I used Euclidean Distance tool on a vector layer (school, point) and in the output raster layer, the distances are in weird unit and the distance ranges from 0.01 to 0.32.

How do I convert the distance into meters?

I need to find area within 250m, (and above 500m, 750, etc.) of the school.

I am using ArcGIS Pro

Comment: If you did the Euclidean Distance in Cartesian degrees, the values are nearly meaningless.  Projecting to an appropriate equal-area spatial reference is warranted.

Comment: Project the vector layer to something with units in metres, like UTM. 0.32 is probably in degrees.